# How to add Add Public Collaborator in GitLab in my Private Repo

Tags: gitlab

Hi I am planning to buy licence of GitLabs
I would like to invite public collaborators to add code on my Repositories created at GitLab
They should be able to Add, Commit, Push.

How can I do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can invite anybody to your gitlab project via their emal-address.
Go to "Project info -> Members" in your Project or group.

After inviting a user, you can choose the role he will become.
The roles controll what the user can do in your repository.

Here you find the list of the [members-permissions](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/permissions.html#group-members-permissions) for each role

[image: Gitlab - invite user]

Comment: Then invited users will be able to do Add, Commit,  Push. But will I be required to make payment for each user.  Actually I m confused on per user licence and this model.

Comment: If you're project is generally open to public collaboration, why not leave it as a public project? That way you don't have to pay for any user licenses for it, and you can still use the gold-level features.

Comment: @BigBansal 1. No, not each user is automatically allowed to push, you can choose roles for each user to say who can push and who not.
2. I am not sure if there is a limit in free version how many users you can add, but I currently have projects with multiple users and I am still in rthe free plan